# Using Templates to specify a Type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to be able to declare a type of a class based on usage.  For example, take a 3 stage pipeline, which has 3 queues connecting them together.  I want to make sure that I connect the stages together with the queues correctly (ex: the queues are going in the right direction, to the right units, etc..)

Here is an extremely simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
template<class in, class out>
class Fifo: public queue{};

class Stage1; class Stage2; class Stage3;

class Stage1{
    Fifo<Stage1,Stage2>* m_fifoOut;
};

class Stage2{
    Fifo<Stage1,Stage2>* m_fifoIn;
    Fifo<Stage2,Stage3>* m_fifoOut;
};

class Stage3{
    Fifo<Stage2,Stage3>* m_fifoIn;
};
```

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve this functionally?  It is preferred to know at compile time that the queues have been incorrectly set up.  However, I am worried that using a template generates unnecessary copies of classes.

Comment: I don't think 'unnecessary copies' are really a concern here. Instead, I would be more worried about the maintenance cost of doing this entirely using templates. That implies that if you *ever* need to construct a pipeline based on runtime information, you will be forced to do a partial rewrite. You could feasibly write a separate tool to check a configuration before it is executed (e.g. by reading pipeline configurations from a file, without using templates to enforce the ordering).

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd try to represent a pipeline a bit more directly. Specifically, I'd try to concentrate on the pipeline stages instead of the FIFO. If you have C++11 available, one possibility would be a variadic template where you specify the types of the pipeline stages, and it automatically generates a FIFO between each pipeline stage and the next.

Comment: I would expect this to work fine in the simple example, however it may not with what I am trying to accomplish, as some stages can have multiple inputs/outputs.

Comment: @Nickker22: in that case, what you're building is really a graph rather than a pipeline. I'm pretty sure it could still be made to work, though it would undoubtedly be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make sure that I connect the stages together with the queues correctly (ex: the queues are going in the right direction, to the right units, etc..)

Just have a meta function that generates the second type, and just specify the first type.

```
template<class In>
struct get_target;

class Stage1; class Stage2; class Stage3;

template<>
struct get_target<Stage1>{
  typedef Stage2 type;
};

template<>
struct get_target<Stage2>{
  typedef Stage3 type;
};

template<class In>
class Fifo : public queue{
  typedef In in_type;
  typedef typename get_target<In>::type out_type;
};

struct Stage1{
  Fifo<Stage1> m_fifoOut;
};

struct Stage2{
  Fifo<Stage1> m_fifoIn;
  Fifo<Stage2> m_fifoOut;
};

struct Stage1{
  Fifo<Stage2> m_fifoIn;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks entirely reasonable as far as it goes. I can assure you that at the company I work for, we regularly do much wilder things with templates than that (you wouldn't want to know), and have never had any issues related to duplicate object code (what I assume is what you are thinking of).

Comment: Yeah, I'm fresh out of college and I am relatively new to using templates.  So I would like to make any new habits of mine the right habits ;).  It's just hard to accept the additional overhead for just wanting a type check.

Comment: As far as your code goes, there's no overhead in terms of memory or speed at runtime, because each class is still just storing a pointer (or two). It's just the compiler that has to work a bit harder to work out each class' type information.